# How can I parse a json string value of a json object in a liquid template?

Tags: liquid, shopify-template

I am rather new to Liquid templates, but I don't seem to find a way to parse a string value to json.
Disclaimer: I am using the [Shopify Liquid Preview extension](https://github.com/kirchner-trevor/vscode-shopify-liquid-preview) for VSCode.

**Input json file**:

The input file contains two properties: `Status` and `Body` and I want to find a way to access the `ItemData.Name` json field inside the Body property.

```json
{
    "Status": true,
    "Body": "{\"ItemData\":{\"Amount\":10.0,\"Name\":\"MyTest\",\"ItemType\":1}}"
}
```

**Expected output**:

```html
<h1>MyTest</h1>
<p>Status: true<p>
```

**Current attempt**:

Trying to use the `json_string` and `json` filter, but that does not seem to work, at first sight.

```
{% assign data = Body | json_string %}
{% assign data2 = Body | json %}
<h1>{{data.ItemData.Name}}</h1>
<h1>{{data2.ItemData.Name}}</h1>
<p>{{Status}}</p>
```

Comment: can you post what do you want to achieve?  json was statis ?

Answer (score 1):

I did this to successfully parse a JSON string in a project of mine:

```
{% assign json_str = cart.attributes.urban-deli-pickup-spot %}
{% assign json_token = json_str | split: ',' %}

{% for token in json_token %}
    {% if forloop.index == 1 %}
        {% assign res = token | split: ':' %}
        {% assign resWithoutQuotes = res[1] | remove: '&quot;' %}
        {% capture pickup_spot %}
            Your amazing truck pickup spot is: {{ resWithoutQuotes }}
        {% endcapture %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{{ pickup_spot }}
```

Starting point ->

**{"postal_address":"Evenemangsgatan 31","requested_delivery_date":"2022-02-03","timewindow_start":"13:10","timewindow_end":"14:00"}**

Result ->

**Your amazing truck pickup spot is: Evenemangsgatan 31**